# How to control the transaction Spring Rest Webservice with JPA?

Tags: web-services, spring-mvc, jpa, jta

I would like to know how to control the transaction in `Spring Rest Webservice`.
If I test with `JUnit` to `Service` and `DAO` without using the `Webservice`(Controller), it is ok. But, when the client program call the webservice process I get the following error.

ENV

```
Spring 3.2.5
JPA 2.0
Eclipselink-2.5.0
Tomcat 7
```

What I need to do for configuration `Tomcat 7`

error

```
14:23:04,427 DEBUG [org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils] Closing JPA EntityManager
14:23:04,427 DEBUG [org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler] Creating new EntityManager for shared EntityManager invocation
14:23:04,434 DEBUG [org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils] Closing JPA EntityManager
14:23:04,436 ERROR [com.ignite.easyticket.core.operator.persistence.OperatorDAO] insert() method has been failed.
javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: 
Exception Description: No transaction is currently active
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.transaction.EntityTransactionWrapper.throwCheckTransactionFailedException(EntityTransactionWrapper.java:87)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.transaction.EntityTransactionWrapper.checkForTransaction(EntityTransactionWrapper.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.checkForTransaction(EntityManagerImpl.java:2015)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.flush(EntityManagerImpl.java:846)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:366)
    at $Proxy12.flush(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:241)
    at $Proxy12.flush(Unknown Source)
    at com.ignite.easyticket.core.operator.persistence.OperatorDAO.insert(OperatorDAO.java:35)
    at com.ignite.easyticket.core.operator.service.OperatorService.addNewOperator(OperatorService.java:37)
    at com.ignite.easyticket.webservice.OperatorController.createOperator(OperatorController.java:30)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
```

Client.java

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
OperatorDTO operatorDTO = new OperatorDTO("CycDemo", "TTF", "01234684101");
String response = restTemplate.postForObject(SERVER_URI + URIConstant.OPERATOR_CREATE, operatorDTO, String.class);
```

**Server Side**

OperatorController.java

```
@Controller
public class OperatorController {
    @Autowired
    private IOperatorService operatorService;

    @RequestMapping(value = URIConstant.OPERATOR_CREATE, method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "application/json; charset=utf-8")
    public @ResponseBody OperatorDTO createOperator(@RequestBody OperatorDTO operatorDTO) {
        Operator operator = new Operator(operatorDTO);
        operatorService.addNewOperator(operator);
        return operatorDTO;
    }
}
```

OperatorService.java

```
@Service(value = "OperatorService")
public class OperatorService implements IOperatorService {
    @Resource(name = "OperatorDAO")
    private IOperatorDAO OperatorDAO;

    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
    public void addNewOperator(Operator Operator) throws SystemException {
        try {
            OperatorDAO.insert(Operator);
        } catch (DAOException e) {
            //throw exception
        }
    }   
}
```

OperatorDAO.java

```
@Repository("OperatorDAO")
public class OperatorDAO implements IOperatorDAO {
    // inject entity manager

    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
    public void insert(Operator operator) throws DAOException {
        try {
            em.persist(operator);
            em.flush();
        } catch (PersistenceException pe) {
            //throw exception
        }
    }
```

web.xml

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-beans.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<!-- Processes application requests -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

servlet-context.xml

```
<annotation-driven />
<!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
<resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

<!-- Configure to plugin JSON as request and response in method handler -->
<beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter">
    <beans:property name="messageConverters">
        <beans:list>
            <beans:ref bean="jsonMessageConverter"/>
        </beans:list>
    </beans:property>
</beans:bean>

<!-- Configure bean to convert JSON to POJO and vice versa -->
<beans:bean id="jsonMessageConverter" class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter">
</beans:bean>   

<context:component-scan base-package="com.ignite.easyticket" />
```

spring-beans.xml

```
<context:annotation-config/>
<context:component-scan base-package="com.ignite.easyticket"/>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
<bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor"/>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
</bean>

<util:properties id="SQL_ERROR_CODE" location="classpath:SQL_ERROR_CODE.properties"/>

<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="JPA"/>
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="jpaVendorAdapter"/>
    <property name="jpaDialect">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.EclipseLinkJpaDialect"/>
    </property>
    <property name="jpaPropertyMap">
        <props>
            <prop key="eclipselink.weaving">false</prop>
        </props>
    </property>

    <property name="loadTimeWeaver">
        <bean class="org.springframework.instrument.classloading.InstrumentationLoadTimeWeaver">
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="jpaVendorAdapter" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.EclipseLinkJpaVendorAdapter">
    <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.eclipse.persistence.platform.database.MySQLPlatform"/>
    <property name="generateDdl" value="false"/>
    <property name="showSql" value="true"/>
</bean>
```

Answer (score -1):

I got one solution [here](http://www.flacom.com/jpa-hibernate-example-using-spring-framework-mvc-3-1/). Now, It is ok.

I change the configuration as below

servlet-context.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd">
    <import resource="spring-beans.xml" />
    <mvc:annotation-driven />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.ignite.easyticket" />
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter">
        <property name="messageConverters">
            <list>
                <ref bean="jsonMessageConverter"/>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="jsonMessageConverter" class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter"/>
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
    <!-- Processes application requests -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```